# Traversing a directory with Python's glob

Tags: python, glob

I need to match all `*.csv.gz` files in a bunch of directories using `glob`.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
data
  /nasdaq100
    /2015
      /20150102
        /A.csv.gz
        ...
        /Z.csv.gz
      ...
      /20161201
        ...
    /2016
    ...
acquisition/
  /script.py
```

In `script.py` I want to traverse all the subdirectories under `nasdaq100` and process the `*.csv.gz` files.

I'm coming up with an empty list when using this:

```
from pathlib import Path
DATA_PATH = Path('../data')
path = DATA_PATH / "nasdaq100"
list(path.glob('*/**/*.csv.gz'))
```

Since `path` is `data/nasdaq100` I thought matching the current directory and sub directories with `*/**/*.csv.gz` would work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code appears to be written under the assumption that the script's directory is the current directory. That assumption is probably wrong.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: That's the actual syntax for pathlib? That's really confusing.

Comment: You can use `Path(...).rglob('*.csv.gz')` to [apply the pattern recursively](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob)

Comment: @user2357112 you're right. When I do `path.cwd()` I get the the root path two directories below. I thought Pathlib handled relative paths for me. How I do use relative paths?

Comment: pathlib works with relative paths just fine. Relative paths just aren't relative to what you wanted them to be relative to. If you want to construct a path relative to the script's directory, start with `__file__` and build the path you want.